# Including Sentry NDK in qmake

Tags: android, cmake, qmake, sentry

I am working on including Sentry in a Qt application. I have the sentry jar and sentry-native aar included in the Android libs folder and am working on linking the Sentry NDK.

Sentry only provides instructions for CMake which I am inexperienced with. How would I include Sentry in qmake?

```
# include paths generated by androidNativeBundle
include (${ANDROID_GRADLE_NATIVE_BUNDLE_PLUGIN_MK})
# change native-lib to your native lib's name
target_link_libraries(native-lib ${ANDROID_GRADLE_NATIVE_MODULES})
```

Where is ANDROID_GRADLE_NATIVE_BUNDLE_PLUGIN_MK, can it be included or would I need to locate and translate a cmake file?
I doubt I need to target ANDROID_GRADLE_NATIVE_MODULES since Qt is already a native module. Am I wrong?

Any help would be greatly experienced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up compiling Sentry separately. It's really not worth trying to integrate with Qmake. Qt Creator 7 integrates really well with CMake.